# Функции словарей: Что возвращает max() для словарей?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Какой критерий для максимального ключа?

```
>>> a = {'b':[1, 2, 3], 'c':[2, 3, 4, 5], 'd':[1234, 6789, 23456]}
>>> max(a)
'd'
>>> a = {'b':[1, 2, 3], 'c':[2, 3, 4, 5], 'd':[1234, 6789, 23456], 'v':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]}
>>> max(a)
'v'
```

Comment: максимальный ключ?

Comment: в чем критерий максимума?

Comment: ну для строк точно определено отношение больше меньше...

Comment: Для символов - алфавитный порядок.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev `max({'я': 0, 'ё': 0}) == 'ё'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Функция `max` принимает любой итерируемый объект, возвращает максимум от его элементов. Если итерировать словарь при помощи `for`, например, то получим последовательность его ключей, поэтому и функция `max` вернет максимальный из ключей. Для строк в python большей считается та, которая идет позже в [лексикографическом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA) (алфавитном) порядке. В первом случае максимальным ключом будет `'d'`, во втором `'v'`.

В общем случае для объектов, для которых нужно найти максимум (без использования аргумента `key` функции `max`, о нем ниже), должно быть определено отношение больше-меньше. Для своих классов нужно как минимум определить метод `__lt__()`:

```
>>> class A():
...     def __init__(self, value):
...         self.value = value
...
...     def __lt__(self, other):
...         return self.value > other.value  # Знак больше вместо меньше вставлен намеренно
...
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return 'A(%r)' % self.value

>>> max([A(1), A(2), A(3)])
A(1)
```

Чтобы получить максимум по какому-то признаку (не так, как определено сравнение для конкретных объектов), можно воспользоваться аргументом `key` функции `max`. Через данный аргумент можно передать функцию, которая будет возвращать параметр, по которому нужно производить сравнение. Типичный пример - найти максимум по длине:

```
s = ['abc', 'ab', 'def', 'dead']
print(max(s))  # максимум по алфавиту - 'def'
print(max(s, key=len))  # максимум по длине - 'dead'
```

Другой довольно типичный случай - есть список кортежей, нужно выбрать максимум по одному из полей кортежа:

```
s = [(1, 10), (2, 9), (3, 8), (4, 7), (5, 6), (6, 5), (7, 4), (8, 3), (9, 2), (10, 1)]
# находим максимальный элемент списка по значению первого элемента кортежа:
print(max(s, key=lambda x: x[0]))  # выведет (10, 1)
# находим максимальный элемент списка по значению второго элемента кортежа:
print(max(s, key=lambda x: x[1]))  # выведет (1, 10)
```

Comment: Скобки не нужны в конце: `max(a,b,c)` и так работает.

Comment: @jfs, так-то да, но это будет вызов функции не с итерируемым аргументом, а с несколькими аргументами.

Comment: Вы иллюстрируете `__lt__`, а не то что max() может списки принимать. Следует использовать `max(a,b,c)`, а не `max([a,b,c])` в Питоне. Также не обязательно `__lt__`  метод определять, к примеру: `max([1], "2", key=len)` работает хотя `[1] < "2"` сравнение не определено (TypeError).

Comment: "Следует использовать `max(a,b,c)`, а не `max([a,b,c])` в Питоне." - возможно более предпочтительно, но уж точно не строго *"следует"*. По поводу аргумента `key` дополнил ответ.

Comment: 1- "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it" 2- я добавил комментарий не к тому что ответ не полон—я бы вообще всё начиная со слов "в общем случае" стёр бы (больше—не всегда лучше), а к тому что объяснение про `__lt__` неправильное.

Comment: @jfs, 1. Zen of Python - это набор утверждений, на которые можно помедитировать, но в итоге сделать как того требует практика. В данном случае пример синтетический, особой разницы нет. 2. Что по-вашему лучше: `max(s)` или `max(*s)`? А если так: `max([1, 2, 3])` или `max(1, 2, 3)`? Можно ориентироваться на количество символов, можно на что-то другое ("красоту"?), смысл не изменится. В любом случае это бессмысленный спор.

Comment: "в общем случае" оставил, но уточнил про аргумент `key`.